# How to update locale after editing a .po file?

Tags: caching, i18n-l10n

I edited a .po file in profiles/l10n_install/translations/ but after this the pages of the site are not updated.

How to update the site after editing a .po file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Import your file from config menu then translate interface import
admin/config/regional/translate/import
and then import your file

Comment: Your English in the answer is unclear. What is "Import your file from config menu then translate interface"?

Comment: just go to this link http://yourdomain.com/admin/config/regional/translate/import and then upload your file

Answer (score 0):

The answer by *Ahmed* tells you to use the "Import" tab provided by the Administration GUI to download the file and (re-)import after editing it.

As an alternative, you may use the CLI and the following sequence of *Drush* commands:

```
$ drush l10n-update-refresh
$ drush l10n-update-status
$ drush l10n-update
```

This is quicker if you are comfortable with the GUI and *Drush*.